# Angular 2 typescript:How to show dropdown list based on radio buttons backend values

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

UI contain radio buttons YES and NO and dropdown, I have created backend API service for radio buttons, where i am dynamically sending YES and NO params values with URL(GET),if user sends YES in response I am getting list of clients, now based on YES params values, how to show it in dropdown options(Listing) angular 2 typescript.

```
URL : http://localhost:9095/api/v1/client/list?isyourClient={Y}
Sample Response :
[{ "userId": "Mind.com","clientCode": "25","clientName": "CORPORATION" },
{ "userId": "forloop.com","clientCode": "275","clientName": "ABC COMPANY" }]
```

This is the sample response I am getting.

Comment: Please add some more infos: Code, Response for Yes and No (JSON?), ..

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<select *ngIf='clients'>
     <option  *ngFor="let client of clients">{{client.clientName}}</option>
 </select>
```

**Code:**

```
    client:Array<any>;
responseHandler(response)
{ 
     this.client = response;
     /*Response is: [{ "userId": "Mind.com","clientCode": "25","clientName": "CORPORATION" },
{ "userId": "forloop.com","clientCode": "275","clientName": "ABC COMPANY" }]*/
}
```